# service-worker registered and precaching works fine, but fetch event is never firing

Tags: service, progressive-web-apps, worker, workbox, vite

I'm quite new to PWA, service workers and workbox. I don't understand why and how the `fetch` event inside my service worker is supposed to be triggered?

I see the log of workbox which is precaching files I've provided as an array:
[image: DevTools log of workbox precache]

How would I serve from cache now and why does my `fetch` event handler won't be fired at all?

My service-worker file:

```js
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.2.0/workbox-sw.js')

workbox.setConfig({
    debug: true,
})

// To avoid async issues, we load strategies before we call it in the event listener
workbox.loadModule('workbox-core')
workbox.loadModule('workbox-routing')
workbox.loadModule('workbox-cacheable-response')
workbox.loadModule('workbox-strategies')
workbox.loadModule('workbox-expiration')
workbox.loadModule('workbox-precaching')

const { precacheAndRoute } = workbox.precaching

const wbManifest = self.__WB_MANIFEST

console.log(wbManifest)

precacheAndRoute(wbManifest);

const cacheNames = workbox.core.cacheNames
const { registerRoute, setCatchHandler, setDefaultHandler } = workbox.routing
const { CacheableResponsePlugin } = workbox.cacheableResponse
const {
    NetworkFirst,
    StaleWhileRevalidate,
    NetworkOnly,
} = workbox.strategies
const { ExpirationPlugin } = workbox.expiration

const cacheName = cacheNames.runtime

const contentToCache = [
    '/',
]

for (const entry of wbManifest) {
    contentToCache.push(entry.url)
}

self.addEventListener('activate', e => {
    e.waitUntil(self.clients.claim()) // Become available to all pages
})

self.addEventListener('install', e => {
    e.waitUntil((async () => {
        const cache = await caches.open(cacheName)
        console.log('[Service Worker] Caching content', contentToCache)
        await cache.addAll(contentToCache)
        self.skipWaiting()
    })())
})

self.addEventListener('push', e => {
    console.log(e.data.text());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
    const { request } = e;
    console.log(request)
    e.respondWith(caches.match(request).then(cachedResponse => {
        // This promise explicitly resolves with "undefined" when there are no matches, all other values are correct
        if (cachedResponse !== undefined) {
            return cachedResponse
        } else {
            return fetch(request).then(response => {
                // Since we can use the response only once, put the clone into the cache and serve the original response
                const responseClone = response.clone()
                caches.open('CACHE_KEY_WHATEVER').then(cache => {
                    cache.put(request, responseClone)
                })
                return response
            }).catch(() => {
                // Retry logic
            });
        }
    }))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`precacheAndRoute(wbManifest);` will both precache (during `install`, add the entries to the cache) **and** route (respond to `fetch` events with a cached response) for all entries that are present in `wbManifest`.

I see that your current code attempts to do both the precaching (in your own `install` handler) and routing (in your own `fetch` handler) for all of those URLs. If you would prefer to handle that yourself, that's fine, but in that case you shouldn't be calling `precacheAndRoute()` at all. You're attempting to do the same thing as that method, but the event listeners for Workbox's `precacheAndRoute()` ends up executing first and take precedence.

Comment: Thanks for the info and clarification about `precacheAndRoute` function but resources (which I've inspect via DevTools' Network tab) are still not served from the cache storage.
A cold cache call shows me my `console.log`s once, fills the cache (which I've also checked on the Application tab inside DevTools) but a second call won't serve them from the cache. My custom `fetch` event-listener isn't either called at all - it contains as you can see in the main thread that it logs the `request` object.